# Why does my touch develop script keep crashing?

Tags: loops, memory, crash, structure, touchdevelop

The question isn't exactly concerned with touch develop rather just basic programming "structure" or syntax.

what I am trying to do is create a simple compass working on the phones heading capability. The heading capability just spits out degree readings to several (like 12) decimal places.

Anyway, even just letting the phone spit out the heading, eventually the phone will crash, why is that? Running out of memory?

The reason I came here is because of this:

I want to update the page with a photo of an associated rotation based on degree readout. I can't figure out how to do something like if 0 < x < 1 post this picture. Since the heading readout varies like 321.18364947363 and 321.10243635471

So currently I am testing this: several if / if else statements saying if heading output is 1 post picture with 1 degree rotation, 2 post picture with 2 degree rotation. This definitely and guaranteed crashes the phone. Why? Memory?

If you are a touch developer, would it be easier and more sane to simply take a round object, center it in relation to a square image and use it as a sprite or object which then you can dictate what angular velocity and position the object has without doing / using 360 individual images.

GAH! Damn character limits / thread format

this is what follows what I last wrote below for anyone that cares :

The concept seems simple enough but I am basically a programming noob, I was all over the place trying to learn Python, Java and C/C#/C++. ( I wrote this on my Windows Phone 8 but I was unable to copy the text ( GAY )  ) I am happy to have come across Touch Develop because it is better for me as a visual learner. (Thanks for the life story )right ? haha

The idea would have been to use this dumb pink against black giant compass with three headings / points of interests namely A fixed relative north, the heading and a position given by the person to be found's lat and long coordinates relative to the finder's phone's current location (lat and long ). This app in my mind would be used for party scenarios. I would have benefited from this app had the circumstances been right, I was lost at a party and I had to take a cab home for $110.00 because I didn't drive to that party.

Comment: Can you post your touchdevelop code so we can look at it? The if statement doesn't sound unusual put have the photo is getting adjusted could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Not sure if this will work

Comment: The script fails when I try to open the code in the editor so I'll just write down basically what I am trying to do: This is my heading

Comment: action heading3 ()
var x := senses - heading 
while x =/ 0 do 
if x < or equal to 1 then 
post 1 degree rotation photo 
if x < or equal to 2 then 
post 2 degree rotation photo 

I'm sorry I'm not able to just post the code but
overall I don't really think it is worth it at this point. 
I'm not sure if my scripts are public to begin with. 
But basically I did that pattern of if this then that 
for 15 photos

The effect I wanted which should hav shown either numbers 
or a rotating dial didn't work... for one, the image doesn't 
stay overlayed, it stacks vertically as it updates then it crashes